# Parsley.js focus on validated div on error

Tags: validation, parsley.js

I need at least one of three fields in my form to be filled in. So I used a parsley validation on a div element encompassing these three fields. Works really well, the only problem is that on error, it does not gain focus like normal inputs.

Here are some more specific details (this is haml syntax):

```
#phone-fields.parsley-group-validate{data:{'parsley-one-child-required' => "mobile_phone|home_phone|work_phone",parsley_validate_if_empty:'true'
  = f.input :mobile_phone, as: :phone
  = f.input :home_phone, as: :phone
  = f.input :work_phone, as: :phone
```

then in my javascript file I add the custom `oneChildRequired` validation

```
      Parsley.addValidator('oneChildRequired', {
        requirementType: 'string', //expect format of string t be input ids separated by '|' e.g. "mobile_phone|home_phone|work_phone" not sure how to allow varying number of requirements so this will suffice
        validateString: function(_value, requirement, instance) {
          var multiSelector = "#enrolment_form_"+requirement.replace(/\|/g, ', #enrolment_form_');// gives multi selector like '"#enrolment_form_mobile_phone, #enrolment_form_home_phone, #enrolment_form_work_phone"'
          var $inputs = instance.$element.find(multiSelector);
          var valid = false;
          $inputs.each(function(i){
            if($(this).val()){
              valid = true; // one input has a value
              return false; //break out of the loop
            }
          });
          // no input has the target value (requirement2)
          return valid;
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

I found in the source code
`return this._focusedField.focus();`

`.focus()` only works on input elements I think.

So to fix it I replaced it with

```
      if(this._focusedField.is(':input')){
        return this._focusedField.focus();
      } else {
        return this._focusedField.attr("tabindex",-1).focus();
      }
```

the else block will trigger a focus on a div element

I wonder if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: PR welcome if you find a generic way to find a good generic way to handle this.